# Adding rdfa lite to Facebook Instant Articles

Tags: facebook, rdfa, facebook-instant-articles

I am new to all forms of coding, so pls forgive me falling over my feet whilst trying to grasp this.

I am trying to setup fb instant articles & am still in the "Production Articles" mode. I have marked up on article that has already been published [What is dog training](http://caninecoaching.co.uk/what-is-dog-training/)

I want to include RDFa Lite syntax as well, but every time I run it through google structured data test it keeps flagging different faults up.

What "BEGINNERS ERROR" am i making her???

Thanks in advance

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" prefix="op: http://media.facebook.com/op#">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://caninecoaching.co.uk/what-is-dog- training/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" title="default" href="#">
  <title>What is dog training?</title>
  <meta property="http://caninecoaching.co.uk" content="Dog Training Article">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <article typeof="http://schema.org/Article">
      <header>
        <!-- The cover image shown inside your article -->
        <figure>

<!--image-->
          <span property="http://schema.org/image"><img src="http://caninecoaching.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/What-is-Dog-Training1a.jpg" property="http://schema.org/url"/></span>
<!--image-->

          <figcaption>Dog training is the process of teaching skills or behaviors to your dog.</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!-- The title shown in your article -->
        <h1 property="headline">What is dog training?</h1>
        <!-- A kicker for your article -->
        <h3 class="op-kicker" property="http://schema.org/description">
Dog training is the process of teaching skills or behaviors to your dog. This can include teaching your dog to respond to certain commands, or helping your dog learn coping skills to certain environments.
</h3>
        <!-- The author of your article -->
        <address>
By <span property="http://schema.org/author">Paul Daly</span> HDipCCB Head Behaviourist at <span property="http://schema.org/publisher">Canine Coaching</span>.
        </address>

<!--Logo-->        
<img src="http://caninecoaching.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/cc-logo-160x-160.jpg" property="https://schema.org/logo" />
<!--Logo-->

        <!-- The published and last modified time stamps -->
        <time class="op-published" dateTime="2016-5-16T13:30" property="http://schema.org/datePublished">May 14th 2016, 1:30 PM</time>
        <time class="op-modified" dateTime="2016-5-16T05:51" property="http://schema.org/dateModified">May 16th 2016, 05:51 AM</time>
      </header>

<!-- Headline -->
      <h2 property="https://schema.org/headline">What is dog training and how does it help our pets?</h2>
<!-- Headline -->

      <div property="http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage">
        <p>Dog training is called classical conditioning designed by the human get a dog performing a desired behavior or skill.</p>
        <p>A person who trains dogs is said to be a dog trainer. There are many methods of dog training and many objectives, from basics to more advanced including, Police, Security, Military, Rescue, Hunting, working with livestock, Dogs for the disabled and many more. As pack animals, wild dogs have natural instincts to cooperate with their fellow dogs. Many domestic dogs will either through instinct or breeding correctly interprets and responds to signals given by a human handler or owner.</p>
        <p>There is much controversy about what is the most effective way to train a dog. Some dog trainers are said to be ‘positive trainers’ as they mostly use positive reinforcement to elicit, motivate, and achieve desired results. An opposing camp comes from ‘traditional’ trainers encouraging the use of punishment, often a physical stimulus used to regain the control of the dog.</p>
        <p>Then there are dominance trainers, who believe all animals have an innate desire to dominate others, and that this dominating behavior needs to be overcome by owner leadership. In practice nearly all trainers use all quadrants of Classical conditioning in their training, and so use both reinforcement and punishment whether they know it or not.</p>
        <p>So what do I mean by this well corrections are a form of positive punishment. Corrections can be physical (i.e. leash correction) or mental (i.e. withdrawing a reward). The dog’s personality, the behavior, and the importance of the correct behavior should all be taken into account in using corrections with your dog.</p>
        <p>In a nutshell <a href="http://caninecoaching.co.uk/positive-or-positive-reinforcement-training/">Positive Reinforcement training </a>is in fact the use of negative corrections to eliminate a behavior and positive rewards to repeat a behavior. Pure positive training does not work because the <a href="http://caninecoaching.co.uk/positive-or-positive-reinforcement-training/">positive reinforcement</a> practice is a basic Classical conditioning technique that rewards dogs for responding accordingly to the trainer’s or owner commands.</p>
        <p>Rewards often come through treats or verbal praise or other types of positive reinforces, such as a tug toy or ball, social interaction with other dogs, or the owner’s attention. The more rewarding a dog finds a reinforce the more work it will do to obtain the reinforce. Or does it or does it just causes additional expenses to the owner and risk the dog to potential to become overweight due to overeating. Studies show that positive reinforcement can also manipulate an animal to show both desirable and undesirable behavior depending on its experience.</p>
        <p>But you add positive punishment (i.e corrections) which studies show that positive punishment has its place in dog training when combined with positive reinforcement you have a sustainable, reliable training method. Training a dog takes time and patience, however with clear and consistent communication your dog will begin to understand what you or your trainer wants from them fairly quickly.</p>
        <p>This corresponds to Animal Cognition the mental capacity of non-human animals. The dog takes in the smells, the sights and sounds to remember something it has been taught. It uses your body language and your energy to gauge how serious you are about getting them to respond to you. All dogs work differently due to the breeds we have created, however they are all they same psychology.</p>
        <p>We teach, we guide and we lead our dogs. Remember training is training whatever method you use or think you use.</p>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp; </p>
      <footer>
        <!-- Copyright details for your article -->
        <small>© <span property="http://schema.org/copyrightHolder">Canine Coaching</span></small>
      </footer>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like below until you get more experience.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" prefix="op: http://media.facebook.com/op#">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://caninecoaching.co.uk/what-is-dog-training/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" title="default" href="#" />
<title>What is dog training?</title>
<meta property="http://caninecoaching.co.uk" content="Dog Training Article" />
  </head>
  <body>
<div>
  <article typeof="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
    <header>
    <!-- The cover image shown inside your article -->
    <figure>
    <span property="http://schema.org/image">
      <img src="http://caninecoaching.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/What-is-Dog-Training1a.jpg"
      property="http://schema.org/url" />
    </span> 
    <figcaption>Dog training is the process of teaching skills or behaviors to your dog.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <h1>What is dog training?</h1>
    <h3 class="op-kicker" property="http://schema.org/description">Dog training is the process of teaching skills or behaviors
    to your dog. This can include teaching your dog to respond to certain commands, or helping your dog learn coping skills to
    certain environments.</h3>
    <address>By 
    <span property="http://schema.org/author">Paul Daly</span> HDipCCB Head Behaviourist at 
    <span property="http://schema.org/publisher">Canine Coaching</span>.
    </address>
    <!--Logo -->
    <span property="http://schema.org/image">
      <img src="http://caninecoaching.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/cc-logo-160x-160.jpg"
      property="http://schema.org/url" alt="canine coaching"/>
    </span> 
    <time class="op-published" datetime="2016-05-16T13:30" property="http://schema.org/datePublished">May 14th 2016, 1:30 PM</time> 
    <time class="op-modified" datetime="2016-05-16T05:51" property="http://schema.org/dateModified">May 16th 2016, 05:51 AM</time></header>
    <!-- Headline -->
    <h2 property="http://schema.org/headline">What is dog training and how does it help our pets?</h2>
    <div property="http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage">
      <p>Dog training is called classical conditioning designed by the human get a dog performing a desired behavior or
      skill.</p>
      <p>A person who trains dogs is said to be a dog trainer. There are many methods of dog training and many objectives, from
      basics to more advanced including, Police, Security, Military, Rescue, Hunting, working with livestock, Dogs for the
      disabled and many more. As pack animals, wild dogs have natural instincts to cooperate with their fellow dogs. Many
      domestic dogs will either through instinct or breeding correctly interprets and responds to signals given by a human
      handler or owner.</p>
      <p>There is much controversy about what is the most effective way to train a dog. Some dog trainers are said to be
      ‘positive trainers’ as they mostly use positive reinforcement to elicit, motivate, and achieve desired results. An
      opposing camp comes from ‘traditional’ trainers encouraging the use of punishment, often a physical stimulus used to
      regain the control of the dog.</p>
      <p>Then there are dominance trainers, who believe all animals have an innate desire to dominate others, and that this
      dominating behavior needs to be overcome by owner leadership. In practice nearly all trainers use all quadrants of
      Classical conditioning in their training, and so use both reinforcement and punishment whether they know it or not.</p>
      <p>So what do I mean by this well corrections are a form of positive punishment. Corrections can be physical (i.e. leash
      correction) or mental (i.e. withdrawing a reward). The dog’s personality, the behavior, and the importance of the
      correct behavior should all be taken into account in using corrections with your dog.</p>
      <p>In a nutshell 
      <a href="http://caninecoaching.co.uk/positive-or-positive-reinforcement-training/">Positive Reinforcement training</a> is
      in fact the use of negative corrections to eliminate a behavior and positive rewards to repeat a behavior. Pure positive
      training does not work because the 
      <a href="http://caninecoaching.co.uk/positive-or-positive-reinforcement-training/">positive reinforcement</a> practice is
      a basic Classical conditioning technique that rewards dogs for responding accordingly to the trainer’s or owner
      commands.</p>
      <p>Rewards often come through treats or verbal praise or other types of positive reinforces, such as a tug toy or ball,
      social interaction with other dogs, or the owner’s attention. The more rewarding a dog finds a reinforce the more work
      it will do to obtain the reinforce. Or does it or does it just causes additional expenses to the owner and risk the dog
      to potential to become overweight due to overeating. Studies show that positive reinforcement can also manipulate an
      animal to show both desirable and undesirable behavior depending on its experience.</p>
      <p>But you add positive punishment (i.e corrections) which studies show that positive punishment has its place in dog
      training when combined with positive reinforcement you have a sustainable, reliable training method. Training a dog takes
      time and patience, however with clear and consistent communication your dog will begin to understand what you or your
      trainer wants from them fairly quickly.</p>
      <p>This corresponds to Animal Cognition the mental capacity of non-human animals. The dog takes in the smells, the sights
      and sounds to remember something it has been taught. It uses your body language and your energy to gauge how serious you
      are about getting them to respond to you. All dogs work differently due to the breeds we have created, however they are
      all they same psychology.</p>
      <p>We teach, we guide and we lead our dogs. Remember training is training whatever method you use or think you use.</p>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <footer>
      <small>© 
      <span property="http://schema.org/copyrightHolder">Canine Coaching</span></small>
    </footer>
  </article>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, I recommend that you use the W3C HTML validator (https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) as there were HTML errors in your original source.

In the future, you can learn to assign a prefix to the vocabularies-in-use and then use `prefix:term` as an alternative to specifying the full IRI (less typing and easier-to-read HTML).

Here is an example of declaring vocabularies:

```
<html
 prefix="
 this: http://example.com/page#
 bibo: http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/
 dbr: http://dbpedia.org/resources/
 dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/
 foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/
 lcsh: http://id.loc.gov/authorities/subjects/
 og: http://ogp.me/ns#
 ore: http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/
"
 lang="en"
>
<body
 prefix="
 schema: http://schema.org/
 cc: http://creativecommons.org/ns#
 vivo: http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#
 swo: http://www.ebi.ac.uk/swo/
"
 about="this:<your-term-here>"
 typeof="cc:Work bibo:Document ore:Aggregation schema:TechArticle"
>
```

Comment: HI, thank you for answering my question. Ive tried this morning in all sorts of variations to get the 3 fields to validate in google sttd. But every field has cleared bar these 3. as soon as I change it to what I think it should be it then produces multiple errors. Can you advise how I should write these fields, also can you also point me in the direction of a good idiots guide for me to grasp. thanks

Comment: I need to see what you've done so I can suggest changes. That data was missing from the original submission, so I had nothing to work with. Suggest you take my proposal, add your attempt and then update your original question. I can work from there.

Comment: Evening Jay below is the changed markup which some how I've managed to increase the number of errors!

Comment: I updated the response based on your new information. The HTML is now valid on Google SDTT and on W3C HTML validator

Comment: Jay your an absolute star!

Comment: But without taking to much more of your time up why wasn't the form I was using, ie <article vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Article">.   <span propert="image"> etc work?

Comment: See updated answer for example. Please accept the answer.

Comment: Jay thank you for all your help. If you have any suggestions or anything I can do to return the favour just send it across. thanks again,